# Casting a MatrixXd to a Matrix3d with RcppEigen

Tags: r, casting, eigen, rcpp

With `RcppEigen`, I need a `Matrix3d` as an argument of a function. But this is not possible, it only accepts `MatrixXd`. I've tried to cast as follows but that doesn' work:

```
Rcpp::List MtoAxisAngle(Eigen::MatrixXd & m)
{
  Eigen::Matrix3d m3 = m.cast();
  ......
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Not tested yet but I think I've found a solution: `Eigen::Matrix3d m3 = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>(m);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the existing matrix in the initialization of the new matrix:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
#include <RcppEigen.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List MtoAxisAngle(Eigen::MatrixXd & m)
{
  Eigen::Matrix3d m3(m);
  return Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("size") = m3.size());
}


/*** R
MtoAxisAngle(matrix(1:9,3,3))
# MtoAxisAngle(matrix(1:16,4,4))
*/
```

Since a call with a non-conforming matrix kills R, you should check beforehand if the size is correct.

Comment: Thanks Ralf. That's simpler than I thought. And thanks for the advice too.